# create new MySQL table using spark JDBC

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I know that we can read and write data from existing mysql tables using spark jdbc. But can we even create mysql table and insert data into it using dataframes? When i try to load file into dataframe and try to write to non-existing table i'm facing null pointer exception.Following is the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:469)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)

Thought table will be created if does not exist.
 Please let me know if we can create a mysql table and load a dataframe content into it? I'm using Spark 2.1.0 version.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello @Mohana can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

The NullPointerException happends when Spark tries to close the connection. There is a NullPointerException, because the connection is null. The reason of that could be that some connection parameters are null.

Comment: Yes, I got this because I mistyped the jdbc url (it was `jdbc://mysql://localhost ...` instead of `jdbc:mysql://localhost ...`). This exception was annoyingly unspecific.